Area of ellipse using Green’s theorem
Given the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, which we want to calculate the area of. Parameterization $\mathbf{r}(t) = (a \cos t, b \sin t), \ t \in [0, 2\pi]$
My book says we can calculate this by choosing the vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y) = \left( -\frac{1}{2} y, \frac{1}{2} x \right)$. The area of the ellipse is then given by
$ \frac{1}{2} \int -y \ dx + x \ dy$
(I tried solving it at I understand that the integral gives the area).
My book says that we can choose between these:
$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = (0, x)$
$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = (-y, 0)$
$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = \left( -\frac{1}{2} y, \frac{1}{2} x \right)$
which corresponds to
$\text{Area}(R) = \int_C x \ dy = - \int_C y \ dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_C -y \ dx + x \ dy$
But how do I know which vector field I should choose when I solve problems like this? My book says nothing about why we chose this exact vector field, and I can't find anything when I search for it online.

Any field with z component of the curl i.e. $(F_2)_x-(F_1)_y$ equal to 1 will do the job. You choose among those to make the line integral simple.

@Ian So every three vector field will give me answer no matter what I'm trying to find the area of - but one of them will just be easier?

Those three will all get you the answer, as will plenty of other much more complicated fields. You just make a choice that is convenient to integrate. In the case of an ellipse, you can choose a parametrization in which $d\mathbf{r}=\langle -a\sin(t),b\cos(t) \rangle dt$, so all three of those fields are fairly convenient since you end up just needing to integrate $\sin(t) \cos(t)$ which is not that bad.
Most likely unless the shape is very weird, one of $\langle 0,x \rangle$ or $\langle -y,0 \rangle$ will be fine.
